# Java - Need help in finding the shortest string of an array, i'm close from what i see but i'm getting an error,

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Here is the code:

```
    class big
    {
        public static int findSum(String[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int sumArgs = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= args.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i] + " " + args[i].length());
            sumArgs = sumArgs + args[i].length();
        } 
        return sumArgs;
    }
        public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] coolArray = makeInputCopy(args);
        int smallest = findShortest(coolArray);
        int largest = findLargest(coolArray);
        int sumArgs = findSum(args);
        System.out.println(sumArgs);
        System.out.println("Smallest Number present: " + smallest);
        System.out.println("Largest Number present: " + largest);
    }
       public static String findShortest(String[] array) {

        String shortestSeen = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i].length() < shortestSeen.length()) {
                shortestSeen = array[i];
            }
        }
        return shortestSeen;
    }
    public static int findLargest(int[] array) {

        int largestSeen = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i > array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] > largestSeen) {
                largestSeen = array[i];
            }
        }
        return largestSeen;
    }

        public static int[] makeInputCopy(String[] input) {

        int[] output = new int[input.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    }
    return output;
    }
}
```

The program was originally intended to scan an input array for strings, list the amount of characters in each word then add the sum of all characters, I'm trying to find the shortest and longest out of this array.

However, when I invoke the method `findShortest(coolArray)` I'm receiving an error in regards to converting a int to string incapability, i can't wrap my head around why.

If this could be explained I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The error is pretty clear... Check your return type against the variable you are trying to assign

Answer (score 0):

```
 int smallest = findShortest(coolArray);

 public static String findShortest(String[] array) {
   ...
```

You're assigning a String (result of findShortest) to an int (smallest). This can't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be gettting

```
Main.java:21: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to String[]
        int smallest = findShortest(coolArray);
                                    ^
```

This is due to  `int smallest = findShortest(coolArray);`You are assigning string to int which is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int[] coolArray = makeInputCopy(args);
> int smallest = findShortest(coolArray);
> // ...
>
> public static String findShortest(String[] array) {
>     // ...
> ```

Two problems with the above:

- `coolArray` is of type `int[]`, but `findShortest` expects a `String[]`
- `smallest` is of type `int`, but `findShortest` returns a `String`

The fix seems easy enough:

```
String smallest = findShortest(args);
```

However, `findShortest` also has a bug:

> ```
> public static String findShortest(String[] array) {
>
>     String shortestSeen = "";
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
>         if (array[i].length() < shortestSeen.length()) {
>             shortestSeen = array[i];
>         }
>     }
>     return shortestSeen;
> }
> ```

Nothing will ever be shorter than an empty string. So this will always return an empty string.

To fix that, you could either set `shortestSeen` to something obscenely long, or you could track the shortest length in a separate variable, initialized to something very large, like this:

```
public static String findShortest(String[] array) {

    String shortestSeen = "";
    int shortestLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i].length() < shortestLength) {
            shortestSeen = array[i];
            shortestLength = shortestSeen.length();
        }
    }
    return shortestSeen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of findShortest() calls for an array of Strings; however, you're passing in an array of integers. This is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the above answers it seems to be a pretty easy fix . However I did a quick and dirty write of a snippet for finding the shortest in an Array of Strings as well, here's the code :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Shortest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] shortest = { "asd", "abc", "defdfdf", "cy" };

        Map<Integer, String> lengthToString = new HashMap();

        for (String s : shortest) {
            lengthToString.put(s.length(), s);
        }
        System.out.println(lengthToString.get(Collections.min(lengthToString.keySet())));
    }
}
```

This could be of some use since I've tried to use Utility class methods instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. If there are two strings with the same length however, it will only print one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static String findShortest(String[] array) {

    String shortestSeen = array[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].length() < array[0].length()) {
            shortestSeen = array[i];
        }
    }
    return shortestSeen;
}
```

you have to initialize shortestseen with array[0] and you have to make this test array[i].length() < array[0].length()  i see another error in findLargest in for loop : array[i] > largestSeen